# How do you shapeshift into other mobs in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On Minecraft there is a mob that is bugging me and I want its loot but I can't because I have no fire resistance and it is too powerful.

How can I shapeshift into other mobs so that I can defeat it?

Comment: Unless you mean the [Morph Mod](http://ichun.us/mods/morph/) then the keys (by default) would be `[` and `]`.

Comment: The mob you wan't to kill is the "Blaze" isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

With vanilla Minecraft, this is impossible. To shapeshift you will need to use a mod.

Here are some ideas on how you could kill that mob using vanilla Minecraft:

- Kill all mobs in a 10 block radius: `/kill @e[type=!Player, r=10]` (beware this will destroy item frames and armour stands)
- Cheat in diamonds to create good tools and armour: `/give @p minecraft:diamond 64`
- Generate a `/give` command for enchanted swords etc: [Use this](http://ezekielelin.com/give/)

---

If Fire Resistance is the only thing you need, you can get it  for 200 seconds using the following command:

`/effect @p 12 200 1`

Answer (score 1):

Well "shapeshifting" would be a mod so I'm going to assume you're using a mod. I use "voids wrath" to install mods so all I have to do is kill the mob to turn into it (i.e. morph). This isn't the best answer I know but for me I just use my keypad to change to different mobs that I have unlocked by killing them.